# How to use SwiftUI Slider in UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, uislider

I've created a Slider in SwiftUI that I would like to use in an XIB file using UIKit, I'm not sure if using a UIHostingViewController would work in this scenario.

Here is the SwiftUI code for the Slider:

```
protocol SnapperSliderDelegate {
    func valueChanged(value: Int)
}

struct SnapperSlider: View {
    @State private var speed = 50.0
    @State private var isEditing = false
    
    var delegate:SnapperSliderDelegate?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Slider(value: $speed, in: 15...70, step: 5.0) { (editing) in
                isEditing = editing
                if editing {
                    delegate?.valueChanged(value: Int(speed))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I use this in UIKit?

Comment: Why not UIKit slider? Use closure instead of the delegate.

Comment: These may help: [Getting started with UIKit in SwiftUI and vice versa](https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/integrating-swiftui-with-uikit/), and [https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-in-uikit/](How to use SwiftUI in UIKit).

Comment: @RajaKishan The SwiftUI slider was perfect for me. It auto includes line indicators at each step and looked good